# Rerun the dag after making last run as success

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

my scenario is as follows;

I have a main dag with two tasks and another trigger Dag should first make the last run of the main dag as success and rerun the main dag every 12 hours.

I wrote my main dag and trigger dag that rerun the main dag every 12 hours but I could not handle making the last run of the main dag as success after trigger dag reruns the main dag, there are multiple running main dag sessions like the below, I want just one running main dag session other old ones should be paused as success.

[image]

Comment: Can you include dag screenshot from the UI and structure your question again

Comment: I already added Dag's screenshot above from airflow ui, the last running session should be paused as a success, and after that dag should rerun.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Python language?